# How to change resolution of the GDM login screen?

Tags: gnome, gdm, 4k-monitor

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on a retina display, and I have everything scaled and looking great, except for the login screen which is super tiny. I figured out how to set the scaling factor to 2 (in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml`) but the actual dimensions remain the same.

How do I up the dimensions of the login screen to 3800x2160?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit `/var/lib/gdm/.config/monitors.xml` (needs `root`)
   It should look something like this:

```xml
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x0a76</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2256</width>
          <height>1504</height>
          <rate>60.001</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Where it says `<scale>1</scale>` change that number to the scaling factor you want. In my case I want `1.5`.

2. For fractional scaling on Wayland (In your case since you want `2` don't do this)
   run

```sh
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash
```

In the shell, run

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

3. Log out
   After logging out, if everything went right the login screen will have the scaling you chose. I tried just locking instead of logging out but the login screen did not update. Make sure you log out and not just lock.

After a lot of trial and error online, I finally found a working method at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/699.